# Creating a panoramic photo

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, panoramas

I want to be able to create a panoramic photo app or something that will be able to stitch multiple photos together (much like google photo sphere), but before I start I want to get a bit more information how it is done.

Is it done using the `UIImagePickerController` framework?

Is there any other useful API's or anything out there I can use?

Can somebody give me a brief overview of how this works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no available native API with stitching algorithm. You should dig into the 3rd party [OpenCV](http://opencv.org) library and check their `stitcher` [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/stitching/doc/stitching.html)

**Basic Key steps of stitching algorithm:**

- Detect keypoints in each input image (eg. `Harris corners`) and extract the invariant descriptors of the images (eg. `SIFT`)
- Match the descriptors between images
- Using `RANSAC`calculate the homography matrix and apply the transformation

Comment: Thanks - how about the panorama feature is this part of the UIImagePickerController framework?

Comment: UIImagePickerController lets you pick/capture the image from the device gallery/camera, it does not stitch you anything

Comment: thank you - but is the panorama feature part of this framework? So if I capture an image I can have the option to take a panoramic photo also.

Comment: No, unfortunately it is not able to capture in-app panorama now with this framework. The stitching implementation is on your side.

Comment: Thanks this is good! I found this post which I think will help me with stitching images [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11752885/stitch-composite-multiple-images-vertically-and-save-as-one-image-ios-objectiv]. Although this is great for stitching but can you help with how you would also be able to take multiple photos (like photo sphere) - again any APIs or frameworks etc?

Comment: The link you provided does not stitch the images as panorama, they will be stitched as a multiple independent images. I strongly recommend you to read some computer vision related topics.

Comment: Ok thank you I will - I have also found this: https://github.com/foundry/OpenCVSwiftStitch which is also specific to swift.