# Stitch multiple images together horizontally (Swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift

I want to stitch multiple images together horizontally and save it as one image. Under [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11752885/stitch-composite-multiple-images-vertically-and-save-as-one-image-ios-objectiv) question I found this suggested solution:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

    func stitchImages(images: [UIImage], isVertical: Bool) -> UIImage {
    var stitchedImages : UIImage!
    if images.count > 0 {
        var maxWidth = CGFloat(0), maxHeight = CGFloat(0)
        for image in images {
            if image.size.width > maxWidth {
                maxWidth = image.size.width
            }
            if image.size.height > maxHeight {
                maxHeight = image.size.height
            }
        }
        var totalSize : CGSize
        let maxSize = CGSize(width: maxWidth, height: maxHeight)
        if isVertical {
            totalSize = CGSize(width: maxSize.width, height: maxSize.height * (CGFloat)(images.count))
        } else {
            totalSize = CGSize(width: maxSize.width  * (CGFloat)(images.count), height:  maxSize.height)
        }
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(totalSize)
        for image in images {
            let offset = (CGFloat)(images.index(of: image)!)
            let rect =  AVMakeRect(aspectRatio: image.size, insideRect: isVertical ?
                            CGRect(x: 0, y: maxSize.height * offset, width: maxSize.width, height: maxSize.height) :
                            CGRect(x: maxSize.width * offset, y: 0, width: maxSize.width, height: maxSize.height))
            image.draw(in: rect)
        }
        stitchedImages = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    }
    return stitchedImages
}
```

However, I don't know how to use it. Can someone make an example on how to use this with an array of images?

Thank you!

Comment: What is the issue? just use the method by passing array of images and get a single image.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out!

Answer (score 4):

a little update with
Swift 4

```
extension Array where Element: UIImage {
    func stitchImages(isVertical: Bool) -> UIImage {

        let maxWidth = self.compactMap { $0.size.width }.max()
        let maxHeight = self.compactMap { $0.size.height }.max()

        let maxSize = CGSize(width: maxWidth ?? 0, height: maxHeight ?? 0)
        let totalSize = isVertical ?
            CGSize(width: maxSize.width, height: maxSize.height * (CGFloat)(self.count))
            : CGSize(width: maxSize.width  * (CGFloat)(self.count), height:  maxSize.height)
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: totalSize)

        return renderer.image { (context) in
            for (index, image) in self.enumerated() {
                let rect = AVMakeRect(aspectRatio: image.size, insideRect: isVertical ?
                    CGRect(x: 0, y: maxSize.height * CGFloat(index), width: maxSize.width, height: maxSize.height) :
                    CGRect(x: maxSize.width * CGFloat(index), y: 0, width: maxSize.width, height: maxSize.height))
                image.draw(in: rect)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Seriously?

The code you found is EXACTLY what you're looking for, but you don't know how to call it?

If you can't figure out how to call a function it's a bit hard to help you in a way that will be useful. Here's some general code that would load an array of images and stitch them together:

```
//Create an array of image names
let imageNames = ["Fish", "Dog", "Eggplant", "Wombat"]

//create an array of images with those names (images must exist in app bundle)
let images = imageNames.flatMap{UIImage(named:$0)}

//Stitch the images together horizontally
let stichedImage = stitchImages(images: images, isVertical: false)
```

You should probably stop and do some reading on Swift. I suggest downloading the Apple Swift book and reading that. It's quite good, and very easy to follow. That's how I learned the language.

Comment: What was the problem you were having?

Comment: I had problem using the images from the array, but I worked it out!

Comment: You should either accept my answer if it solved your problem, or post your own solution if you think my answer did not address your problem. Saying "I figured it out" doesn't help other people reading this question, which is the main point of this site.